# How to add a Rich Text Box to a Tab item so that can be added to a Tab Control in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, tabitem

How to add a RichTextBox to a Tab item so that can be added to a Tab Control and display corresponding content in the RichTextBox dynamically in MVVM format.

**ViewModel**

```
private ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabControl()
        {
            ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs= new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();

            return Tabs;
        }
```

**Controller**

```
  private void AddNewTabItem(string selectedItem)
    {
    try
        {

            System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox richtextbox = new System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox();
            richtextbox.Name = "richtextbox" + selectedItem;
            BrushConverter BC = new BrushConverter();
            richtextbox.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(BC.ConvertFrom("#FF098BBB"));
            richtextbox.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.WhiteSmoke;
            richtextbox.IsReadOnly = true;

            TabItem m_tabItem = new TabItem();

            m_tabItem.Header = selectedItem;
            m_tabItem.Name = "tab" + selectedItem; 


            if (TabControl.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                TabControl.Items.Insert(0, m_tabItem);
                TabControl.SelectedIndex = msgTracerTabControl.Items.Count - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                TabControl.Items.Insert(msgTracerTabControl.Items.Count - 1, m_tabItem);
                TabControl.SelectedIndex = msgTracerTabControl.Items.Count - 2;
            }




            m_tabItem.Content = new System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox();
            m_tabItem.Content = richtextbox;
            Tabs.add(m_tabItem);
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {

        }

    }
```

**View**

```
<TabControl  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TabControl}"  }"/>
```

I have used this code and working fine and this is not in MVVM this is WAF Architecture in that i'm using MVVM concept.

Comment: this is not MVVM compliant - there must be no TabItem or any gui related element in your viewmodel

Comment: sorry it is not MVVM only MVVM concept iam using over there

Comment: MMV concept means nothing ! ==> you can't do that <ItemsSource="{Binding TabControl}"> because <TabControls> contains <TabItems> which are gui element - and it is waiting for class associated to datatemplate - you mix everything....

Comment: Its working fine it is Architecture i.e WAF but the thing is richtextbox is not adding to the Tabitem which we had already done traditional WPF .

Comment: you can't do that <ItemsSource="{Binding TabControl}"> because <TabControls> contains <TabItems> which are gui element

Comment: it's not Gui Element it is present in the ViewModel and the function code is written in the Controller so <TabControl> is not GUI element and please look into the Question once again , Iam binding the <TabControl> i.e Collection of Tabitems to the Tabcontrol in the GUI

Comment: yes, that's what i said. TabItem is a gui element and they can't be in the ItemsSource collection !      ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelItem} must contains ViewModelItems associated to a datatemplate

Comment: sry in WPF Application Framework it is be done by this way so Tabitem has to bind in this way what i have doing and i learnt from the architecture of the WAF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not thinking MVVM. In a ViewModel you would not directly access UI elements but would rather set up bindings and data templates which would render your Viewmodels correctly. The correct approach is to have 2 viewmodels, 1 to act as a master and the second to act as the underlying DataContext for each tab.

A simple example would be something like this:

**MainViewModel**

```
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private int _tabSuffix;
        public ObservableCollection<TextViewModel> TextTabs { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TextViewModel>();

    public DelegateCommand AddNewTabCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        AddNewTabCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnAddNewTabCommand);
    }

    private void OnAddNewTabCommand()
    {
        TextTabs.Add(new TextViewModel()
        {
            Header = $"Tab #{_tabSuffix++}"
        });
    }
}
```

**MainView**

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Add new tab item" Command="{Binding AddNewTabCommand}"></Button>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding TextTabs}"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <!-- Defines the header -->
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type so44497239:TextViewModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

            <!-- defines the context of each tab -->
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type so44497239:TextViewModel}">
                    <RichTextBox Background="#FF098BBB" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" IsReadOnly="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

**TextViewModel**

```
public class TextViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }
        public Brush ForegroundBrush { get; set; }

        public string Document { get; set; }
    }
```

In this example, the main viewmodel has no knowledge of the View but merely adds items to it's own `ObservableCollection`. The `TabControl` itself, through the binding to TextTabs, adds it's own tab items and renders them using the `ItemTemplate` and `ContentTemplate` properties.

Download code [here](https://github.com/barracoder/SO44497239)

Comment: No I'm using MVVM concept but Actually it is Architecture WAF .so i want to   add the Richtextboxes in each tab that are already binding to the Tabcontrol as i mentioned in the Question. so pls modify your answer @Mark Green

Comment: @Ajay, if you look into my answer, you'll see that each tab has a RichTextBox. It is included in the ContentTemplate of each TabItem. This is the correct way.